# statically placing hooks on PE file's IAT

Tags: c++, pe, function-hooking, iat

recently I started writing my own PE library for C++, and wanted to implement **static IAT/EAT hooking**, (basically hooking by patching the file instead of hooking at runtime), I managed to successfully iterate all the thunk data and retrieve FTs/Names etc.

So where's the issue?
Well...

[image: IMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME]

As you can see in this scheme, the *PE Loader* **replaces the IMAGE_THUNK_DATA with the actual dynamic address at runtime**, so, statically, you would have an offset, say `0x28010`, and at runtime the PE Loader overwrites it with `module_base + 0x28010`, where module_base would be the dynamically obtained base address of (always as an example) `USER32.dll`.

If you still don't understand where I want to get; to statically hook the function I would have to do the following steps, taking as an example `MessageBoxA` function in `USER32.dll`

1. **copy** the **original function** in the **main module memory** (say `.text` section) and save the address, we're going to use this as an "original" for the **detour** (the original function which gets called/returned at the end of the detour, to not break anything)
2. **write/patch** the actual **detour function** in the main module memory (again, say `.text` section) and use the address as the detour function (the offset to replace instead of the FTs)

but then here's the problem, replacing the FTs with the detour, the PE Loader would calculate the FTs like `USER32.dll` + `detourOffset`, where it should instead calculate `mainModuleBase` + `detourOffset`.

one way to "fix" this would be replacing the FTs with the ""ready"" address, so base + detour, but we're talking about STATICALLY hooking IATs, so **we dont have a base address**.

Other than having to patch something that hooks the IAT at runtime, any idea how I could achieve this?